# sql enterprise manager - Existing sql jobs are not showing in sql enterprise manager

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I cannot view the sql jobs in sql enterprise manager when I log on to the machine that has the SQL Server database.
I can see the jobs when I open the Database using Enterprise Manager on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

SQL jobs are not part of the database, but of the SQL Server itself.

Comment: I meant Jobs that you see under SQL Server Agent under Management in Sql Server 2000

Comment: I know, me too. If you're connecting to different SQL Servers you'll see different jobs.